# Suppose we have two std::vectors v1 and v2 and we dont want to combine these in a struct. How to transform v2 the same way v1 was transformed by sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685272/how-can-i-sort-a-vector-based-on-sort-of-another-vector). The only difference is the constrain that the two vectors cannot be combined in a struct.

Suppose we have a vector

```
std::vector<double> v1 = {9.0,5.0,3.0,2.0,1.0};
```

Now we sort the vector `v1`. Let `v2` be given by

```
std::vector<std::string> v2 = {"you?","are","how","there","hello"};
```

How to transform v2 the same way v1 was transformed by sort?

Comment: Whether the two vectors are or are not combined in the same struct makes no difference, whatsoever, to the overall algorithm.

Comment: Use an array of indices.  [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976).  Also read the note at the end of the answer given at the link.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Would also go that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382252/sort-array-by-first-item-in-subarray-c/46382976#46382976), you can use an array of indices to "sort" the vector of doubles, and just use the resulting index array to index the vector of strings.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v1 = {5.0,9.0,3.0,2.0,1.0};
    std::vector<std::string> v2 = {"are", "you?","how","there","hello"};

    // Create an array of indices, starting from 0
    std::vector<int> index(v1.size());
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    // "Sort" the index array according to the value in the vector of doubles
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), 
              [&](int n1, int n2){ return v1[n1] < v1[n2]; });

    // Output results
    for (auto i : index )
      std::cout << v2[i] << " " << v1[i] << ", index is " << i << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello 1, index is 4
there 2, index is 3
how 3, index is 2
are 5, index is 0
you? 9, index is 1
```

---

Note:

I changed the original data to illustrate how the index array works.

Answer (score 3):

The abstraction you are missing is the ability to view the vectors as one item. That's the role that a vector of indices is a proxy for in another answer.

I think it is worth mentioning that there are libraries that provide such a concept (often under the name "zip"). For example, with range-v3:

```
std::vector<double> v1 = {5, 9, 3, 2, 1};
std::vector<std::string> v2 = {"are", "you?", "how", "there", "hello"};

// Sort the vectors
ranges::actions::sort(ranges::views::zip(v1, v2));

// Output results
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
  std::cout << v2[i] << " " << v1[i] << ", index is " << i << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution uses a helper `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
void MySort(std::vector<T> t, std::vector<int>& helper)
{
    struct StructHelper
    {
        T t1;
        int num;
        StructHelper(T t, int i): t1{t}, num{i} {};
        bool operator<(const StructHelper& other) const
        { return t1 < other.t1; }
    };

    std::vector<StructHelper> shVector;

    for(int i=0; i<t.size(); ++i)
    {
        shVector.emplace_back(t[i], i);
    }

    std::sort(shVector.begin(), shVector.end());
    helper = std::vector<int>(t.size());

    for(int i=0; i<t.size(); ++i)
    {
        helper[i] = shVector[i].num;
    }

}

template<typename T>
void MySortUsingHelper(std::vector<T>& t1, const std::vector<int>& helper)
{
    if(t1.size() != helper.size()) throw std::out_of_range("not same size");
    std::vector<T> t2(t1.size());

    for(int i=0; i<helper.size(); ++i)
    {
        t2[i] = t1[helper[i]];
    }

    t1 = t2;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<double> v1 = {9.0,5.0,3.0,2.0,1.0};
    std::vector<int> helper;

    MySort(v1, helper);

    std::vector<std::string> v2 = {"you?","are","how","there","hello"};

    MySortUsingHelper(v2, helper);

    for(auto elem : v2)
    {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[You can run the above code online](https://godbolt.org/z/4fHYbK) to see the following output:

```
hello there how are you?
```

Comment: ok, how about 3 separated vectors?  4 vectors?  10 vectors?  Your solution may work for two vectors, but as you see, it does not scale very well if another vector of items is thrown into the mix, as is often the case when dealing with parallel arrays or vectors that cannot be put into a single struct (for whatever reason).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That is true. Your answer got an upvote.